# How Can I Decrease Touch Lag for JavaScript Touch Input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, touch

I'm trying to build a Point of Sale app for ChromeOS using HTML5 and JavaScript. I'm using Materialize and jQuery for front end. When I try typing a number very quickly using the on-screen number pad, sometimes numbers are skipped. A good example would be trying to type **1752703**, since it's my employee ID at my current job. Even though the CSS effect engages to show I pushed all the numbers (the ripple effect), I may end up with something like 17203 instead of the full number.

Is there any way I can improve touch performance? Is it the type of screen I'm using? What could be causing this to happen? If it's because my Chromebook is capacitive, it's not a big deal, because I could deploy this on any device I could get Chromium OS to run on. But if it's something programmatical that I can improve, that's the first step I'd like to take.

Here is the basic code I'm using for just punching in a whole number:

```
$(".numBtn").click(function(){
 input(Number($(this).text()));
});
```

And here is an example of it in action (apologies for lack of styling):

[Live Demo](http://xbit.technology/pos/XBitPOS)

Comment: what do you mean by "css effect engages to show"?

Comment: The material design ripple effect happens on the buttons, which would indicate that they were pressed, or, at the very least, "moused" down on. But I lift my finger, so it should trigger a click. But the lag makes it so it doesn't :(

Comment: did you try debugging?

Comment: If you have done the debugging and all the numbers are being captured as you press them, but due to the lag they are missing to show up, you may try writing native javascript code.

Comment: That's more than likely the next step I'm going to take. However, it's getting better the more I dig for ansewrs. Since Siavas told me about the problem being pinch to zoom, I've found that touch events for Chrome in general are cumbersome and can ruin a simplified experience when it's wanted. I just updated the live demo with ALL the things I've added to help reduce the delays.

Comment: Also try passive listeners: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/06/passive-event-listeners

Comment: I added the passive option, but I don't really see any difference. Isn't it only for scrolling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### First

The problem seems not to be the device itself, but rather the effect of having a touch-enabled device which supports *pinch zooming*.

On most of these devices, by default, there is a 300-350 ms on-click delay which allows most of the users to double click, or as mentioned, pinch zoom.

Google has brought a solution for this issue in 2014, when they have removed this delay by still keeping the pinch zoom function on.[<sup>(1)</sup>](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2013/12/300ms-tap-delay-gone-away)

The quick fix for this is only one line of code in the `<head>`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

This meta tag is going to disable pinch zoom for your website only by telling the browser "*this is how I need to be displayed, so there's no need for zooming in the page*". The purpose of it is mainly to allow a better user experience in websites with responsive design.

I have tested your website with the new meta tag and the delay seems to disappear. There is still a very small delay when you tap very fast, but the most of the users won't be able to do it such quickly.

---

### Second

Another potential solution is to use a plugin called Tappy which replaces the click event with a tap one, promising "*that it will allow you to execute code immediately on touch devices, eliminating the 300ms delay that click events have*[<sup>(2)</sup>](https://github.com/filamentgroup/tappy/#why)."

The plugin repository can be found [here][3], where you can also look at the implementation instructions - especially at this one, which is a modified version that binds the tap event to all `<a>` elements:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").each(function(){
        $(this).bind("tap", function(){
            window.location.href = this.href;
        });
    });
});
```

Note that you will need jQuery to use this plugin. In case you don't use jQuery, write a comment and I will provide a vanilla JavaScript (potential) solution.

---

#### References

(1): https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2013/12/300ms-tap-delay-gone-away

(2): https://github.com/filamentgroup/tappy/#why

Comment: I just tried that, and updated the code on the live demo. I'm using a Chromebook R11 on Chrome 54, 64 bit. It still allows me to pinch zoom. Is there something I'm missing? Do I need to place this meta tag before my stylesheet? I also tried adding the "touch-action" property and applied it to the html tag and body tag. Still nothing. :/ Is there a difference between the pinch-to-zoom on Chrome for desktops and laptops and Chrome for mobile? I just tried it on my Galaxy S7 and it works flawlessly.

Comment: I just feel like there's a lot of overhead on Chrome for desktop/Chromebooks. I went to **chrome://flags#enable-pinch** and disabled it. Now pinch to zoom is gone, but there is still a pretty noticeable delay. My one concern is having people like me who have grown very efficient on a touchscreen numberpad not be able to input the right number fast enough. :/

Comment: @RickYoder, I have added a second potential resolution for you problem. Have a try with it and tell us how it goes.

Comment: This is an incredible library. Thank you for sharing it. I can now tap as fast as I want and there's NO lag. However, Tappy disabled the material design wave effect I had, but I can probably trigger it within jQuery with the tap event. Fantastic! I'm marking your answer.